# How can I use list/vector elements as objects arguments to a function in R?

Tags: r, call, expression, eval

I programmatically evaluated several models, whose names are in a vector `models`. How can I then use the function `mtable` with them, calling them programmatically?

Here is an example :

```
library(memisc)
a <- rnorm(100,0,1)
b <- rnorm(100,0,1)
c <- rnorm(100,0,1)
d <- rnorm(100,0,1)
mod1 <- lm(a ~ b)
mod2 <- lm(c ~ d)
models <- c("mod1", "mod2")
mtable(mget(models,envir=globalenv()))
```

I then get an error: `"no method available for 'getSummary' for an object of class 'list'"`.

What can I do? I tried `call` and `do.call` but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `do.call`:

```
do.call(mtable, mget(models,envir=globalenv()))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I tried different combinations with do.call but apparently not this very simple one... **ashamed**

Answer (score 5):

Without `mget()`:

```
do.call(mtable, lapply(models, as.symbol))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers were helpful to me, as well, but the focus Joel's particular example obscured the general point, which I figured out by experimenting.  It's this:

Given a function which accepts a variable number of arguments:

```
fvar <- function(...) {do something}
```

suppose that the arguments you want to pass are already contained in a list:

```
myargs <- list(a=1:3, b=c(2, 3, 4))
```

You could pass them individually, e.g.:

```
fvar(myargs[[1]], myargs[[2]])
```

but that only works if your code knows the structure of the list.

`do.call()` allows you to pass whatever is in your list as the series of arguments given to the function:

```
do.call(fvar, myargs)
```

This is more general, since your code doesn't have to figure out what the list's particular structure is, as long as you can assume that it's appropriate for the function.

(`do.call` does essentially the same thing as Common Lisp's `apply`, by the way.)

Comment: I think you want `fvar(myargs[[1]], myargs[[2]])`, or even `fvar(a=myvar[[1]], b=myvar[[2]])`.

Comment: (Realized that the comment I was trying to add wasn't relevant, but can't delete it completely.)

Comment: Maybe there would be situations in which myargs[1] would be appropriate, but you're right.  I'll edit the answer.